# Did Stan Lee finish his cameo shooting for the upcoming Avengers 4 movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, stan-lee, cameo, avengers-endgame

Now that Stan Lee is dead, I am wondering if I'll be able to see his legendary cameo in the upcoming Avengers 4 movie.

Did he finish shooting for it?

Comment: Star Wars didn't seem to have any problem with using CGI to recreate dead actors, Marvel could easily do the same with Stan Lee if they wanted.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer: And both franchises are owned by Disney.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Star Wars didn't do it at the last minute, though. It had been planned for quite a long time. Also, one of the recreated actors in Star Wars wasn't actually dead at the time of the recreation. She was just a lot older, though she has unfortunately died since then.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Star Wars also had controversy sparking the usage of Peter Cushing (Tarkin) in Rogue 1 on whether or not it should have been done. That was with an actor who died well over 20 years ago. They might use unpublished footage, but for Leia and Stan Lee, I think most fans would feel it is too soon to CGI them into a movie.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Also, the characters in *Rogue One* had major plot-related roles, even though Leia's was brief. (See also *Blade Runner 2049*.) Lee's cameos are never plot-crucial; the appeal of his cameos is purely "hey, it's Stan Lee having fun!"

Comment: Ironically, the last movie he appeared in while  living was a DC movie, not MCU.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Don't you mean a Sony movie?

Comment: @JLRishe Ah you’re right, I forgot about Venom.

Comment: I hope they don't CGI replace him, but instead his passing is referenced in some way, maybe have an end credit scene where the Watchers state it is sad there representative on earth is no longer with us or something.

Comment: I did a major rewrite of this question to bring it up to date.   I don't believe this alters the spirit of the question.   If anyone has suggestions or edits, please feel free.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Stan Lee filmed a cameo for Avengers 4, according to Director Joe Russo.

> "So, Stan, typically we try to get him out — he doesn't love to fly —
> so we try to get him out for his cameos around the same time," Russo
> stated. "So if we have other movies shooting on the same lot that
> we're on, for instance Ant-Man 2 **or Avengers 4,** we group his cameos
> together and then move him from one set to the next and kind of get
> him through his cameos in one day."
>
> <sub><sup>[IGN:UK - STAN LEE ALREADY FILMED HIS AVENGERS 4 CAMEO](https://uk.ign.com/articles/2018/11/13/stan-lee-already-filmed-his-avengers-4-cameo)</sup></sub>

And we've finally been able to see the cameo now that the film has aired

> Specifically, Lee turns up in a scene set at a secretive US Army base
> in 1970s New Jersey, where a younger-looking Lee (with dark hair and
> moustache) drives past the compound and mocks the military men inside.
>
> “Hey man,” he shouts, “make love not war!” before driving off over the
> horizon with a mystery woman in the car beside him.
>
> <sub><sup>[Stan Lee’s final Marvel cameo in Avengers: Endgame bids farewell to a legend](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/film/2019-04-27/stan-lee-avengers-endgame-cameo/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I heard that they also filmed a bunch of just random stuff "to be inserted in the future where it seems appropriate." That was just hearsay, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @Draco18s - In the Ant Man extras you see Stan filming various lines that haven't been included in a film yet. Probably enough for fifty films if they cut them up and play their cards right.

Comment: I haven't seen it, but that sounds like what someone told me last night, yes. The more I made (to someone else) was that they've "got cameos for the next 20 years. Hope they 3D scanned him, too."

Comment: You could now update this to say yes, they did include a Stan Lee camio

Answer (score 22):

Stan Lee may have
 cameos in [six upcoming movies](https://www.inverse.com/article/50756-stan-lee-cameo-avengers-4-captain-marvel), of which four are Marvel movies: *Captain Marvel, Avengers 4, X-Men: Dark Phoenix*, and *Spider-Man: Far from Home*.

Update: [According to Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/movies/2018/11/12/stan-lee-no-cameo-x-men-dark-phoenix/), Lee will not appear in Dark Phoenix.

Comment: Sure enough he will be CGI-ed in. Not really much of a challenge these days.

Comment: @Damon:   Recreating an actor is an expensive time-consuming process.   It *is* a challenge.

Comment: @Damon Not only is it expensive and time-consuming, the results tend to get mixed reception. Many people considered the *Rogue One* CGI to be well in the realm of the uncanny valley. Also, since the point of Stan Lee's cameos is "hey, it's Stan Lee", rather than something in-universe and character-based, there's little reason to continue the tradition now that he's no longer alive.

Comment: I'd anticipate easter eggs.  Something like a hotdog cart labelled as "Ol' Stan's New York Style Hotdogs" and a really young person saying "my grampa left me this cart..."   or in a similar vein.

Comment: @Criggie Or Larry Lieber as a UPS guy apologising for having to "fill in for the usual guy"

Comment: Maybe a character called Stan Lee will be written into the Marvel universe?  In fact I'd be surprised if this hadn't already happened in some kind of Spiderman alternate timeline.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Well I'm not sure. The third Matrix movie wasn't _that_ bad (CGI-wise) and that was 15 years ago. The 50-year-younger-50-lbs-more-muscle Arnold Schwarzenegger seen in "Genisys" looked pretty convincing to me, too. Remember Gollum? Over 15 years ago, and pretty convincing. Zemeckis' Beowulf (Winstone at least) wasn't that great, admitted (though Jolie bought me) -- again, over 10 years ago. Getting a believeable cameo (which is what, 2-3 seconds in the back of a scene?) would be no technical challenge to a studio. That's something you can _almost_ do mostly-believeably at home.

Comment: @KyleStrand There's a running theory, especially since the Guardians 2 cameo (where a remark tied in to a prior appearance), that he was indeed playing the same character each time.

Comment: @Damon Non-human characters are much easier. No comment on the others; I haven't watched them, or haven't seen them in years. Note, though, that Leia's role in *Rogue One* was mere seconds, and Rachel's in *2049* barely longer; the first was not uniformly well received, and the second was extremely expensive.

Comment: @Izkata I'm aware of that, but that's not the *purpose* of his cameos.